# Mvvmcross Override style in fragment

Tags: mvvmcross

I needed to be able to override the theme of a fragment in an MvvmCross project.
My code for the OnCreateView on the fragment was :

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.my_fragment_layout, null);
        }
```

The problem with this is that the binding context is created with the fragment activity context, while to be able to override the theme used by my fragment, I need to use a different context  formatted with  my predefined style like this:

```
Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(Activity, Resource.Style.FragmentStyle);
```

And there is no way to override the default context used to clone the context in the MvxBindingContext. So I ended up having the OnCreateView like this :

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(Activity, Resource.Style.FragmentStyle);

            if (BindingContext == null)
                BindingContext = new MvxAndroidBindingContext(context, new MvxSimpleLayoutInflater(Activity.LayoutInflater), DataContext);
            else
                this.EnsureBindingContextIsSet(inflater);

            return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.my_fragment_layout, null);
        }
```

This is working now, but I am not sure if handling the binding context construction here is safe. If only the default context was overridable, that would be perfect

Thanks

Comment: Can I ask why you are using ContextWrapper for fragments?
If you use a FragmentTransaction to add your Fragment at runtime that theme is applied to the Fragments as well.

Comment: In my case, I use the fragment in static mode (in the layout). I didn't try dynamically

Comment: If you've got comments/suggestions about how the fragment code could be improved (e.g. if something needs making public, protected or virtual) then please consider commenting/contributing on https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/771 which is the future of Mvx fragments :)

Comment: Hi Stuart. I'll be pleased to do so